# Sheets.Count on inactive sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want my macro to select the last sheet on an inactive workbook "WbCopy", but Sheets.Count works only when the workbook "WbCopy" is active. Do you have any suggestions how to make it work also when the "WbPaste" is active? The code resides in workbook "WbPaste":

```
Sub CopyPaste()

Dim WbCopy As Workbook
Dim WbPaste As Workbook

Set WbCopy = Workbooks("copy.xlsm")
Set WbPaste = Workbooks("paste.xlsx")

WbCopy.Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: if the code resides in `WbPaste`, should;nt the file be `Workbooks("paste.xlsm")` and not `Workbooks("paste.xlsx")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
WbCopy.Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Activate
```

to:

```
WbCopy.Worksheets(WbCopy.Sheets.Count).Activate
```

**Note**: if you have code in `WbPaste`, it needs to be `.xlsm` extension.